# Unbind ZoomIn in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using a Mac and would like to use `cmd+=` to switch between open windows in VSCode (1.6.1).

By default that key is bound to `workbench.action.zoomIn`.

I tried following [these](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule) instructions to unbind that key, but so far have not had success.

In `keybindings.json`, I have:

```
  { "key": "cmd+=",                 "command": "-workbench.action.zoomIn" },
```

This doesn't seem to have any impact, however, as I still am able to zoom in with `cmd+=`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbinding seems to be broken. You should consider filing a bug here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

> would like to use `cmd+=` to switch between open windows in VSCode

Then you don't need to unbind the current shortcut for `workbench.action.zoomIn` first. Just create a new keybinding like this one to overwrite the existing one:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+=",
  "command": "workbench.action.switchWindow"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, issue submitted: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14720